# How to create and train own model with own dataset?

Tags: tensorflow.js

I want create and train own model. If not possible to create own, any way to train other models? (Yolo, MobileNet, Coco?)

There some requirements:
- I know only JS (tried Python, no, i don't continue, i can't, Python best language, but i can't, sorry)
- Performance, at least 24 FPS, like real-time detection
- Own dataset freedom (like file `/dogs/pitbull/01.png`)

I tried Python, but i don't/can't work in Python due of 10 years experience with JS doesn't lets me use Python

Thanks for everyone for help

Answer (score 1):

This answer is written by an IBMer.

If you want to build a model like the one described (image classification/object detection) without having to deal with python - and you want to use it with javascript in a browser, you can try the tooling available at https://cloud.annotations.ai/. It works with a IBM Cloud account but you can stay go on with the free tier - so you just need to register, at least to do your first experiments.

You'll find here https://github.com/cloud-annotations code and boilerplate to use your model on different platform.

It is not an advanced tool but it enables you to put your hands on the topic.

Comment: thanks for reply. tool looks promising, but it's cloud-based, i have nvidia gpu and i want train on my local machine. i want use in node.js as server-client with websocket/webrtc

Comment: So if you want run all on premise, you should take a look at tensorflow.js: https://www.tensorflow.org/js/tutorials
but it seems to me that Node.js isn't much covered/supported.

While being similar to your skills (and having some problems with not C syntax like programming language, like python), I tried to run premade models on nodejs and inside browser with different results. I just posted a question about my experiments: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60221268/different-predictions-if-running-in-node-instead-of-browser-using-the-same-mode

Comment: Lotti, thank you for experimenting for me. yes node.js isn't supported good, but for me no need too complex, i tried, really, tried. learned basics of python, even now can finish some tests, but language isn't for me